# Breaking the rock using eggs

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, experimental-physics

Is it possible?
Can I break a rock with eggs if I get great speed of egg almost like a Jet and using millions eggs. there is no air resistance and we can accelerate the egg slowly to be like a Jet speed with low acceleration. we can use enough energy. I don't care about egg is broken after break the rock.

Comment: Remember that tiny dust particles can punch a hole in a spacecraft. So yes, an egg could do it - in space. In the atmosphere, air resistance will squash the egg before it arrives at the rock.

Comment: [Waterjet cutter's](https://www.boulderes.com/resource-library/waterjet-cutting-101) water exit speed, at the nozzle, can reach over $1000 m/s$. And egg mostly can be modelled as a liquid, so if you would increase it's kinetic energy to about $25 kJ$, probably you could break thin rock sheets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easy, if you allow for relativistic speed. At a few tens of kilometers per second (about earth's orbital speed), minor forces like chemical bonds or electrostatic attraction between electrons and nuclei already cease to play a role. Egg and stone would simply turn into a mixed plasma for an instant, and the plasma would break the stone into pieces. Once you get to a significant fraction of the speed of light, you'd also be fusing nuclei. In any case, a single egg is ample amount of ammo. Please, don't overdo it, the majority of people on earth does not wish to die a sudden, violent death...

Comment: obligatory https://what-if.xkcd.com/1/

Comment: @Quassnoi Exactly what I had in mind :-)

Comment: @Quassnoi In a rare conjunction, Schlock has the better explainer: https://www.schlockmercenary.com/2000-11-05

Comment: of course i will don't overdo it. because it is too expensive ;-D

Answer (score 12):

If water can create the Grand Canyon and the Dakota Badlands, then with enough eggs and time you can certainly break a rock. Just throw eggs at the rock continuously for a million years or so.

Comment: Important: remember to alternate arms to maintain arm symmetry.

Comment: Well, the canyons were formed by *rivers*, not by water alone. Any naturally flowing water will carry sand and stones with it which will cut into the stone, producing even more sand and stone for the water to carry. A pure fluid, let alone a rather viscous one, would have much more trouble. Then again, I'm certain you can crush the egg shells to increase the effect...